# App is rejected using non-public API LSApplicationWorkspace

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-privateapi

My iOS App is rejected from Apple Store review with the following issue:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> LSApplicationWorkspace, defaultWorkspace
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

But I can find any code about these APIs. Anyone know which part will contain these APIs ?

Answer (score 2):

My blindfold shot in the dark (edit: not sure why it matters that it's dark if I'm blindfold): Make sure that if you have any testing related pods or libraries, that they are not included in the target you use for deployment. Calabash for example probably does make use of private APIs to get work done that'd not be possible otherwise, but it's not meant to be on the app you release.

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same error. Calabash is referencing LSApplicationWorkspace. After excluding references to Calabash for release builds, the app was not rejected from review any longer.